# Use Python to get table of frequency of hours from log file

Tags: python, logging, text

I have a log file that looks like this:

```
10.0.0.153 - - [12/Mar/2004:12:23:41 -0800] "GET /dccstats/stats-hashes.1year.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1582

216.139.185.45 - - [12/Mar/2004:13:04:01 -0800] "GET /mailman/listinfo/webber HTTP/1.1" 200 6051

pd95f99f2.dip.t-dialin.net - - [12/Mar/2004:13:18:57 -0800] "GET /razor.html HTTP/1.1" 200 2869

d97082.upc-d.chello.nl - - [12/Mar/2004:13:25:45 -0800] "GET /SpamAssassin.html HTTP/1.1" 200 7368
```

I want to count how many logs there are for each hour and sort them from most to least frequent. For these 4 logs, the result should be the following.

[image]

How do I do this with only the packages that come with a **standard release of Python 3**?

I could look for the position of the first colon in each line, then extract the 2 characters after that position. However, I fear that there could be other colons beforehand.

Is there a more "intelligent" method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I could look for the position of the first colon in each line, then extract the 2 characters after that position. However, I fear that there could be other colons beforehand

Instead of looking for the first colon, you can

1. look for the ' - - '

   ```
   log_message = '216.139.185.45 - - [12/Mar/2004:13:04:01 -0800] "GET /mailman/listinfo/webber HTTP/1.1" 200 6051'
   log_hour = log_message.split(' - - ')[1].split(':')[1]
   ```
2. or directly the first open bracket ([) and then the colon

   ```
   log_hour = log_message.split('[')[1].split(':')[1]
   ```

To get the hour frequency you can use the following code

```
hour_frequency_dict = {hour:0 for hour in list(range(24))}
for log_message in log_message_list:
    log_hour = int(log_message.split(' - - ')[1].split(':')[1])
    hour_frequency_dict[log_hour] += 1
hour_frequency_dict = {hour: frequency for hour, frequency in hour_frequency_dict.items() if frequency > 0}
```

Answer (score 2):

One straightforward way would be to get the fourth element from the log lines, i.e., the date, from the date extract the hour, and use a `Counter`.

```py
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> 
>>> cnt = Counter()
>>> with open('log') as f:
...     for line in f:
...         hour = line.split()[3].split(':')[1]
...         cnt[hour] += 1
... 
>>> cnt.most_common()
[('13', 3), ('12', 1)]
```

Another more extendable way for parsing your Apache access logs would be to use a regex.

```py
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> cnt = Counter()
>>> p = r'\S+ \S+ \S+ \[.*?:(.*?):.*?\] "\S+ \S+ \S+" \S+ \S+'
>>> pat = re.compile(p)
>>> with open('log') as f:
...     for line in f:
...         m = pat.match(line)
...         hour = m.group(1)
...         cnt[hour] += 1
... 
>>> cnt.most_common()
[('13', 3), ('12', 1)]
```

**Notes**

- You could use a `dict` instead of a `Counter` (and its `most_common()`) and sort by the value.
- If you want the `hours` as `int`s you could use `cnt[int(hour)] += 1` (with a check to make sure that `hour` is not `None`)
- The second method is more extendable because you can do more with your logs. For instance, the snippet below gives you all the fields in a log line in a tuple:

```py
>>> p = r'(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) \[(.*?)\] "(\S+) (\S+) (\S+)" (\S+) (\S+)'
>>> pat = re.compile(p)
>>> with open('log') as f:
...     for line in f:
...         m = pat.match(line)
...         m.groups()
... 
('10.0.0.153', '-', '-', '12/Mar/2004:12:23:41 -0800', 'GET', '/dccstats/stats-hashes.1year.png', 'HTTP/1.1', '200', '1582')
('216.139.185.45', '-', '-', '12/Mar/2004:13:04:01 -0800', 'GET', '/mailman/listinfo/webber', 'HTTP/1.1', '200', '6051')
('pd95f99f2.dip.t-dialin.net', '-', '-', '12/Mar/2004:13:18:57 -0800', 'GET', '/razor.html', 'HTTP/1.1', '200', '2869')
('d97082.upc-d.chello.nl', '-', '-', '12/Mar/2004:13:25:45 -0800', 'GET', '/SpamAssassin.html', 'HTTP/1.1', '200', '7368')
```